# For Loop in batch language

Tags: csv, batch-file

SO I have a CSV file that looks like the such:

```
ComputerName,UserID,192.168.0.xx
ComputerName,UserID,192.168.0.xx
```

I am trying to write a batch loop script that will read the IPs that are in the script and ping them this is what I have so far:

```
setlocal Disable DelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=" %%a in (test.csv) do(

Set line=%%c
ping %line%

)
```

Setting the variable works, but it seems like I am not able to read anything from the batch file as I am getting returned an error that says :

```
%%a was unexpected at this time
```

I was wondering how can I be able to fix that or what am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues, but you are very close. I have updated your script and noted the corrections.

```
REM You want to _Enable_ delayed expansion. This is a single word.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Your delimiter needs to be a ,
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (
    Set line=%%c
    REM You need to access the line value enclosed in !'s since it is delayed expansion.
    ping !line!
)
```

Alternately, you could do this as a one-liner from the command prompt (no batch file needed):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %a in (test.csv) do PING %c
```

Answer (score 0):

The `delims=` bit means that there are no delimiters and so the entire string is treated as one unbroken line instead of being split on the comma like you want. Change it to

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (
    Set line=%%c
    ping !line!
)
```